# Can Firestore's data be managed by angular service?

Tags: angular, firebase, service, google-cloud-firestore

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];
  // heroesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Hero>;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService, private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    // this.heroesCollection = this.afs.collection('toh');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();

    // this.heroesCollection.valueChanges()
    // .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
    .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
}
```

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeroService {

  private heroesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Hero>;
  heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService,
              private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.heroesCollection = afs.collection('toh');
    this.heroes = this.heroesCollection.valueChanges();
  }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the heroes
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return this.heroes;
  }

  getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the hero
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}`);
    // return of(HEROES.find(hero => hero.id === id));
    
    return this.heroesCollection.doc<Hero>(String(id)).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

I am working on a basic example (Tour of Heroes) in Angular.io with firestore. For readability and management, the firestore-related parts were created in the service and each component was referenced. The problem is that the first time I call it, the data is loaded well, **but when I click on another place and then go back, the data does not appear.** I do not know if this is due to the life cycle of the component or if the data refering part is wrong. 
**You can see and excute the code written in the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toh-firestore) I uploaded**, which shows that the heroes component is now accessing the firestore through the service. If you change this part to a commented part (call it directly from the component), you can see that the data is normally retrieved even if you click elsewhere and then return.
I think it's the same code, and I just want to write the data to the service and manage it, so I want to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my getHeroes() method like

```js
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  // TODO: send the message _after_ fetching the heroes
  this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
  return this.heroesCollection.valueChanges();
}
```

In this code, I return the current state of my collection rather then Observable variables.